# Puppet: Defining custom resource types wrapping exec resources and using optional "unless"

Tags: puppet

The following code example is purely academical but it illustrates my question pretty well.

```
define touch($file=$title, $unless='/bin/false') {
    exec { "/bin/touch ${file}": unless => $unless }
}
```

If I define my own resource type that wraps another *exec* resource and I want to **add an optional "unless" condition** that I - if set - pass to the optional "unless" condiftion of *exec* - do I have to preset the field with '/bin/false'?

My understanding is that for each catalog run and all uses of this custom ressource type this resource's unless check will then spawn a bash process running '/bin/false' if the unless field of "touch" hasn't been set .

What I actually intend is not to do any "unless" check at all if the field hasn't been set - including calling "/bin/false".

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use undef instead of '/bin/false', unless will run only if it is set:

```
define touch($file=$title, $unless=undef) {
    exec { "/bin/touch ${file}": unless => $unless }
}
```